# How to compare list of models with queryset in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have a serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClass
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        user = self.context.get("request").user
        users = data.get("users")
        users_list = User.objects.filter(organization=user.organization)
        return data
```

users will print a list of models like this:
[<User: User 1>, <User: User 2>]

users_list will display a queryset:
Queryset:
<QuerySet [<User: User 1>, <User: User 2>, <User: User 3>]>

I want to write a query which checks if list of models e.g.users are present inside a queryset users_list. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you need to compare every `User` organization with `request.user` organization. If you have list of objects, You can do it without `QuerySet`:

```
user = self.context.get("request").user
users = data.get("users")
for u in users:
    if u.organization == user.organization:
        # do what you want if that's True or anything
return data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as Models are [hashable if the model has a primary key](https://github.com/django/django/blob/34b328814976a2e2f7907361a494202763649f3f/django/db/models/base.py#L603-L606):

```
>>> users
[<User: user1>, <User: user2>]

>>> users_list
<QuerySet [<User: user1>]>

>>> set(users).intersection(users_list)
{<User: user1>}

>>> set(users).difference(users_list)
{<User: user2>}

# and so on
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the ids of all the users and convert queryset into the list and then validate the data

```
users_list = list(User.objects.filter(organization=user.organization)
.values('id'))
if {'id': self.context.get("request").user.id} in users_list:
    # do what you want if that's True or anything
```

users_list.

Comment: I have to compare the users_list with users, which is a list of Model class objects